# How do I use Mac dictation in Google Docs?

Tags: google-chrome, voice-dictation, google-docs

I'm using macOS 12.3.1 and Google Chrome 101, and I want to be able to use macOS's dictation in Google Docs, but I couldn't activate the dictation prompt in Google Docs.

I tried assigning a different key in Sys prefs > Keyboard > dictation, but dictation still won't activate in Google Docs.

My questions are:

- How do I use Mac dictation in Google Docs, and some other apps, like the terminal?
- Can I activate dictation from command line?

Comment: These are two completely different questions and should be split in two different questions.